# Datagrid view not populating when mysql parameters are used

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, parameters

My thinking is that the problem lies with the adapter. However, I'm still very green and would appreciate any help. I've searched this forum and have had no luck with any of the resolutions I've found (pebkac probably). The application is simple, use textbox input in a parameterized select statement to populate the datagridview. The query will execute but the grid remains empty. VS2017, MySql8.0

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myConnectionstring = null;
        string mySelect = "SELECT * FROM part_data WHERE 'SERIAL' = @test; ";
        string tb7 = textBox7.Text;
        //Set Connection String And Create Connection
        myConnectionstring = "server=localhost;user= admin; database= trace;port=3306;password= admin;Allow User Variables=True";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionstring))
        {   //Create Command Object
            //MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelect, myConnection);



            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
               // myCommand.Prepare();
                //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test",tb7);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySelect, myConnectionstring);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test",tb7);
                //debug to see final select statement
                richTextBox1.Text = mySelect;


                adapter.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show("Query Failed" + ex);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance it looks as though your query might be bad. Try using backticks around the column name.

```
SELECT * FROM part_data WHERE `SERIAL` = @test;
```

Comment: I believe `SERIAL` is a keyword.  He probably needs to use backticks (`)

Comment: I apologize, SERIAL is a column name. I just tried the backticks and it worked.  This is a small test app to help implement parameters before I modify the actual app.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the query without parameters, there is no need to do it like that, then try the DataSourceView of your dataset.